# Running Snippet in full screen as reviewer then clicking back arrow redirects me to another question

Tags: support, review-queues, stack-snippets

I recently got my 500 rep points and had access to the reviewing actions, but one of the questions I was reviewing had a PHP related snippet. I tried to test that snippet on full screen which doesn't open the code execution in a new tab. Instead it opens in the same tab, so once I tested it on the new tab. I tried to get back with the back arrow, but the question disappeared.

Comment: I am curious why you would need to execute a snippet as part of reviewing a question. Can you elaborate on the use-case?

Comment: I just wanted to check the output of the snippet out of curiosity and that might also give me a better idea about what I am reviewing.

Comment: @CodyGray In the Close and Reopen queues it's useful to see if the code in a snippet actually reproduces the issue, especially if there are existing typo/no-repro flags/votes on it. If the question specifies that an issue only occurs at specific screen sizes, then going full screen might be required to see what's happening. (I got one like this today.)

Answer (score 8):

Don't use the back arrow in your browser. Instead, click on the close button at the top right of the screen to close a full-screen snippet. This applies whether or not you're using the review queues.

Comment: I just noticed there was a close button on the top right corner I didn't see it the first time, I mean I get the idea but don't you think it would be hard to see for someone or anyone trying it for the first time? especially if it was covered by something with the same color?

Comment: Well now we have your question and this answer to help too.

Comment: Should I post about that in a new question?

Comment: What would the new question be? If you have a specific proposal for making the close button more visible, that would be an appropriate [[meta-tag:feature-request]].