# Close button when trying snippets on full screen might not be noticable

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-snippets, user-experience

On my recent [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416641/13541620), since I was trying the stack overflow snippet in full screen for the first time I couldn't notice that there was a close button on the top right corner, and that would be the case especially when the button and the background or anything behind it has a similar or the same color, and that would make it absolutely invisible especially for people reaching it for the first time.

I would recommend at least warning users about the close button before going to full-screen snippet for the first time.

Comment: What is your typical expectation for closing or exiting a full-screen window on a computer? What would such a 'warning' look like?

Comment: I guess having it closed by the [Esc] key would be a plus, it's the basic of any fullscreen feature. Though here it's not fullscreen, it's full-page.